# shell scripting quotation

Tags: shell

I have written a small script with which I take the name of a File.

```
#objectname
echo "objectname"
read ON
```

Can't get simpler.

I do some processing with the file I get.

```
gpg -c --no-use-agent "$ON"
```

For example if I have a file `a.exe` --> It will encrypt it and give me a file with a different md5 and an extension. Now, the file looks this way `a.exe.gpg`

Now, if I give it a bind the name of the file directly.

like this for example:
Taken from : this [link](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-list/2004-September/msg04889.html)

```
# This works
fileName='a.exe.gpg'
md5sum=$(md5sum ${fileName})
echo $md5sum
```

it returns it properly.

What if I want to do it dynamically.

This is what I tried:

```
#does not work
gpg -c --no-use-agent "$ON"
fileName= `$ON.gpg`
md5sum= $(md5sum ${fileName}) 
echo $md5sum
```

I get this bug here: `upload.sh: 1: upload.sh: Fire.exe.gpg: not found` and the program does not exit.

May I ask where exactly is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
fileName= `$ON.gpg`
```

1. There should be no space after `=`.  (Also look at the next line.)
2. You used back-quotes, which *execute* `$ON.gpg` rather than simply evaluating it.  Back-quotes are the same as `$(...)` but less elegant.  Use double-quotes for this.

Read [Greg's wiki entry on quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) for an ultra-detailed explanation with opinionated commentary.  :-)

Comment: My pleasure.  The whole wiki is fascinating and extremely educational.  It's maintained by a fellow who frequents the #bash channel on FreeNode.  If you go there, prepare to be insulted *and* educated.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when making assignments in shell script. Don't use spaces in any sides of the `operator=`. Try the following:

```
fileName="$ON.gpg"
md5sum=$(md5sum ${fileName})
```

Note that the variable and the assignment `operator=` are together with no space.

Also, when you use backticks as `` `expression` ``, it will be executed by shell like using `$(expression)`, as pointed by user ghoti.

Answer (score 1):

You goofed on fixing the filename.

```
fileName="$ON.gpg"
```

Comment: I am sorry but I have a different error now:

`upload.sh: 48: upload.sh: 96b2edbf09638837d4c2feadb3d3bb3e: not found`